# Does THREE.CanvasRender() support mesh.updateAnimation()

Tags: three.js

I just saw the work of http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/md2_morphtarget_example/
,It is amazing.So, I try to see if it can run on Three.CanvasRender.But it doesn't work.it seems updateAnimation doesn't work. Can anyone tell why.

Answer (score 0):

`CanvasRenderer` doesn't support morph targets yet.